# Convolutionnal autoencoders and dimensionality reduction

Tags: convolution, autoencoder, dimensionality-reduction

I have a question regarding the importance of convolutions steps before dimensionality reduction in a convolutional auto-encoder (CAE).

In many implementations I have seen, CAEs use a "flatten" layer to transform the last convolution layer (with dimensions: *H , W , C*) into a classical one-dimensional layer (dim: *H x W x C*) before some fully connected layers to produce the "code" of the auto-encoder.

However, I have noticed that most of the time, the resulting flattened layer has actually more dimensions than the input layer ! Therefore, I have the intuition that those plain Convolutional AutoEncoders are clearly over-complete and therefore at risk of identity mapping learning.

**So my question :**

What do you gain from doing convolutions before the fully connected layers compared to traditional stacked auto-encoder ? (Is the convolutional encoding part really useful for dimensionality reduction ?)

Note that I would like to use CAE for unsupervised pretraining before doing classification and I am wondering if CAE are better choice than SAE.

Thanks in advance for you thoughts on the question.